# OpenCv cv2.arcLength(cnt,True) and cv2.contourArea(cnt) error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

When I am trying run following code:

```
img = cv2.imread('index4.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
contours,hierarchy, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2) 
cnt = contours[0]
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
```

I am getting following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-f8db5433a171> in <module>()
----> 1 perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)

error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:285: error: (-215) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function arcLength
```

and Then:

```
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
```

and `Error`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-c660947e12c8> in <module>()
----> 1 area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:320: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function contourArea
```

## N.B:

> python3, opencv version: '3.3.0'

How can I solve these issues ?

Comment: how many elements in `cnt`?

Comment: @Miki `cnt.shape = (275,)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contours are the *second* element in the returned tuple from `findContours()`, not the first. Previously in older versions of OpenCV, `findContours()` only returned two results---but now it returns three--and the additional value became the *first* element of the returned tuple.

From the [docs for `cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours):

> ```
> cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) → image, contours, hierarchy
> ```

Thus

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```

will fix you up. Or if you only want the contours, you don't need to use throwaway variables like `_`, just index the tuple that is returned:

```
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)[1]
```